# Multiplying a number by the elements of a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Could anyone help me with what's wrong with the code below:

```
k = {'boy':[2,3,6,8], 
     'girl':[3,5,7,9]
    }

n = 2

m = {}
for (key, value) in k.items():
    m[key] = [
        n * value for value in k.values()
    ]
    
print(m['boy'])

[[2, 3, 6, 8, 2, 3, 6, 8], [3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

I need a result that would multiply n by each value of the list elements within the dictionary. SSo the result is supposed to come out as:

```
m = {'boy':[4,6,12,16],
     'girl':[6,10,14,18]}
```

Comment: ` k.values()` or just value ?

Comment: k.values(). pointing to the values in the dictionary

Comment: `n * v for v in value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k = {'boy': [2,3,6,8], 
     'girl': [3,5,7,9]}
n = 2

m = {key: [v * n for v in value]
     for key, value in k.items()}
```

If you are not familiar with comprehensions, this gives the same result

```
m = {} 
for key, value in k.items():
    l = [] 
    for v in value:
        l.append(v * n)
    m[key] = l
```

The version with comprehensions is faster and in my opinion more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can't multiply lists with the `*` operator as this is reserved for repeating lists:

```py
[0] * 5

result: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You could do this in two ways:

1. You use `numpy` arrays which do support this behaviour.
2. You explicitly multiply each element. For example like:

```py
k = {'boy':[2,3,6,8], 
     'girl':[3,5,7,9]
    }

n = 2

m = {}
for (key, value) in k.items():
    m[key] = [
        n * one_value for one_value in value
    ]
```

I also just noticed you were overwriting the variable `value`. Be careful with this as this can lead to hard to find issues. Preferably always use an unused name for a variable where possible, unless you really mean to reuse one. Also you were selecting from `k.values()` which are all the lists in that dictionary, not just the one you want to be manipulating.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the key and values properly :

```
k = {'boy':[2,3,6,8], 
         'girl':[3,5,7,9]
        }
    
n = 2

m = {}
for (key, value) in k.items():
    m[key] = key
    m[key] = [
        n * val for val in value
    ]
    
print(m['boy'])
print(m['girl'])
```

output :

```
[4, 6, 12, 16]
[6, 10, 14, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that , you are iterating on the main dictionary values with `k.values()` , instead you can just use the `value` in the item.
like

```
m[key] = [
        n * val for val in value
    ]
```

And a bonus one-liner for you

```
m = {key:list(map(lambda x: x*n, value)) for key,value in k.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop (for value in k.values()) value is a list so when you multiply it by n this will repeat the elements of list n times.
instead of k.values() you can use value as follow:

```
k = {
    'boy':[2,3,6,8], 
    'girl':[3,5,7,9]
}

n = 2

m = {}

for (key, value) in k.items():
    m[key] = [v*n for v in value]
    
print(m)
```